# How to sort when you are using UNION operator in Oracle SQL. I am using two select statements and UNION operator, I want to sort results of both query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to solve HackerRank SQL - **The PADS** question.

The Question is:

Generate the following two result sets:

1. Query an *alphabetically ordered* list of all names in **OCCUPATIONS**, immediately followed by the first letter of each profession as a parenthetical (i.e.: enclosed in parentheses). For example: `AnActorName(A)`, `ADoctorName(D)`, `AProfessorName(P)`, and `ASingerName(S)`.
2. Query the number of ocurrences of each occupation in **OCCUPATIONS**. Sort the occurrences in *ascending order*, and output them in the following format:

   ```
   There are a total of [occupation_count] [occupation]s.
   ```

   where `[occupation_count]` is the number of occurrences of an occupation in **OCCUPATIONS** and `[occupation]` is the *lowercase* occupation name. If more than one *Occupation* has the same `[occupation_count]`, they should be ordered alphabetically.

My Solution is:

```
SELECT NAME || '(' || SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1) || ')' 
FROM OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY NAME 
UNION  
SELECT 'There are a total of ' || COUNT(OCCUPATION) || ' ' ||  LOWER(OCCUPATION) || 's.' 
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
GROUP BY OCCUPATION 
ORDER BY OCCUPATION;

OP:
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
(It seems, we cannot use ORDER BY BEFORE UNION)
```

I revised my code to:

```
SELECT NAME || '(' || SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1) || ')' 
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
UNION  
SELECT 'There are a total of ' || COUNT(OCCUPATION) || ' ' ||  LOWER(OCCUPATION) || 's.' 
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
GROUP BY OCCUPATION 
ORDER BY NAME, OCCUPATION;

OP:
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-00904: "NAME": invalid identifier
```

Please, help me out here.

Comment: In general (for anyone else wanting to know how to order the results of a UNION/INTERSECT/MINUS, you would need to follow the `order by` keywords with one or more column names from the top `select` list (in your case there is only one column, so `order by NAME || '(' || SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1) || ')' `, but you could also alias it and order by the alias name), or else one or more positional identifiers referring to the *n*th column, e.g. `order by 1` to order by the first column in the `select` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're wanting to output two ordered sets of data in one query, the easiest way is to assign an identifier to each query and then order by that and the column you want to order by, e.g.:

```
SELECT info
FROM   (SELECT 1 qry, NAME || '(' || SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1) || ')' info
        FROM   OCCUPATIONS
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 qry, 'There are a total of ' || COUNT(OCCUPATION) || ' ' ||  LOWER(OCCUPATION) || 's.' info
        FROM OCCUPATIONS
        GROUP BY OCCUPATION)
ORDER BY qry, info;
```

Note that, because the two queries aren't going to return the same rows, I've used a `UNION ALL`, since a `UNION` does a DISTINCT on the resultant data set, whereas `UNION ALL` doesn't. Also, I'm assuming that if you had two different people with the same name and occupation (e.g. different birth dates), you should output both rows, rather than one row?

Note also that when you have a `UNION`/`UNION ALL` query, the output columns inherit the column name from the first query, which is why your second query was giving you the invalid identifier error (you hadn't given your column an alias!).

Comment: Hey.. it is working fine, thanks for the solution and explanation.
Also, got to learn how to use identifier and difference between UNION and UNION ALL :)

Comment: I answered your question regarding how to do the ordering with the UNION'd queries, but I have to say that MT0 is entirely correct in that your solution doesn't fulfill the question you posted from hackerrank, which calls for two resultsets. And the ordering of the second query needs tweaking

Answer (score 3):

> Generate the following two result sets

You are **NOT** generating two result sets. You are performing two `SELECT`s and trying to merge them into a single result set using `UNION` and that is not what the question asks for. Stop using `UNION` and use two queries.

The first result set would be:

```sql
SELECT NAME || '(' || SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1) || ')' 
FROM   OCCUPATIONS 
ORDER BY NAME;
```

The second result set would be:

```sql
SELECT 'There are a total of ' || COUNT(OCCUPATION) || ' ' || LOWER(OCCUPATION) || 's.' 
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
```

and then you need to `ORDER BY` the number of occurrences **AND** then by the occupation name (which I leave to you to solve).

Comment: Yup... got the output using two separate queries also. Thanks!

CODE:

SELECT NAME || '(' || SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1) || ')' 
FROM   OCCUPATIONS 
ORDER BY NAME;
SELECT 'There are a total of ' || COUNT(OCCUPATION) || ' ' || LOWER(OCCUPATION) || 's.' INFO
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY INFO;

Comment: @JanviChitroda The final `ORDER BY` clause is not correct as the question asks you to "Sort the occurrences in ascending order ... [and] if more than one Occupation has the same occupation_count, they should be ordered alphabetically." You are sorting the occurrences alphabetically (as part of the `info` string) and not in ascending numeric order and you do not include the occupation in the order clause.

Comment: I am sorting the INFO string (eg: There are a total of 3 doctors, There are a total of 4 actors.) Here the start of string (There are a total of ) will be same for all records so it will check for the occupation count and after that the name of the occupation. So, it is indirectly sorting 1st by occupation count then occupation name.

I am getting the output from this, but I am not sure if the method is correct as I have recently started learning SQL. Please correct me if the approach is incorrect.

Comment: @JanviC If you sort as numbers then `1` < `2` < `12` however, if you sort as strings then `'1'` < `'12'` < `'2'`. You are sorting by `INFO` which is a (concatenated) string and it will sort an occupation with 12 people before an occupation with 2 people; that is **NOT** in ascending order of occupation count. You need to sort directly on the numeric `COUNT` value and not on the concatenated string.

Answer (score 0):

Please try here hope this help:

```
select name||'('||SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1)||')' as col
from OCCUPATIONS
UNION ALL
select 
'There are a total of '||count(occupation)||' '||LOWER(occupation)||'s.' as col
from OCCUPATIONS
group by occupation
order by col
;
```

If we need to tune up performance and we also know the 2 selection is not duplicate, just use **UNION ALL** .